# captcha in codeigniter which are copied from custom php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I copied a captcha code from custom php and put it into a codeigniter controller the function for captcha is

```
function captcha(){
    session_start();
    $ranStr = md5(microtime());
    $ranStr = substr($ranStr, 0, 6);
    $_SESSION['cap_code'] = $ranStr;
    $newImage = imagecreatefromjpeg("cap_bg.jpg");
    $txtColor = imagecolorallocate($newImage, 0, 0, 0);
    imagestring($newImage, 5, 5, 5, $ranStr, $txtColor);
    //header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($newImage);
}
```

when i run this, it directly give me the whole image in my view ,it does not show my form. How can i change this code for my codeigniter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split your form page and the captcha in two controllers .

for example:

A controller: show your form and add a "<img src='B controller`s url'" tag.

B controller: controller just for your captcha show:

```
captcha();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the CAPTCHA Helper from codeigniter. Here is the reference: [Captcha Helper Doc](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html)

Comment: because it uses a database which i dnt want 2 use

Comment: You don't have to use a database if you don't want to, you can save the image with the text as the name and check it when the form is posted.